# fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory in VSC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, eigen

I am beginner-programmer and I wanted to run a code which includes “Eigen/Dense” library. However, I could not add this library into the Visual Studio Code (VSC). I followed the following instruction, but it did not work.

•   Open command panel (Shift+CMD+P on OSX or Shift+Ctrl+P on Windows and Linux).
•   Search for 'Extlibraries: Add external library' and press Intro.
•   Input external directory or file path (here I entered the path of Eigen directory which I download from its website).
•   Input name and press Intro (here I entered Eigen)
Could you please help me with this problem? I am waiting for your responses. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Eigen is a header only library. That means that there is no library binary that needs to be linked. As such, you just have to make sure that the Eigen directory is correctly placed in your include paths. So, if you have the `Eigen/Dense` file is located at `C:\some\path\to\Eigen\Dense`, then the included path needs to be `C:\some\path\to\`.